# How to get valid input parameters that are constrained by Typescript generics

Tags: typescript

I have access to an external library that looks like the following:

```js
type ParamMap = {
  a: "a1" | "a2";
  b: "b1" | "b2";
};

type Params<T extends keyof ParamMap> = ParamMap[T];

export const fn = <Namespace extends keyof ParamMap, Val extends Params<Namespace>>(
  namespace: Namespace,
  key: Val
): string => `${namespace}.${key}`;
```

Is there a way to get the type of `key` when `namespace` is `a` with only access to `fn`? I assume it would look something like: `Parameters<fn>['a', infer T]` but I can't get it to work.

Comment: [ms/TS#41040](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41040) makes this difficult.  I can't find an approach that works purely in the type system; if we can drop down to the value level a bit I can use [higher order fn support](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions) to tease it out [like this playground link shows](https://tsplay.dev/WPOzzm). Does that suffice? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for, thank you @jcalz! Is there a way to do the same entirely in typescript-land? I want to determine if the key works even without having access to the actual fn in the current scope (just the type of fn). I'm guessing that's the root of the issue...

Comment: I'm not sure what "TypeScript land" is; you need to at least *pretend* you have access to the function, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NDJe8W) (see `null! as Fn`).  Does that work?

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I meant, thanks! Also, noticed in another question you were looking for examples for why null! might be necessary - I suppose this is one of them?

Comment: Okay, I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really do this directly because the type you care about is a [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) on the `Val` type parameter, and there's currently no way to [infer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) a generic constraint.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#41040](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41040).

The only way I can think of to do this is to jump through a lot of hoops both with *types* and with *expressions*. These expressions will be emitted to JavaScript, so you will have some code at runtime that serves absolutely no purpose.

---

First, let's start with `typeof fn`, which I'll give the name `Fn` here:

```
type Fn = <
    Namespace extends keyof ParamMap, Val extends Params<Namespace>
>(namespace: Namespace, key: Val) => string
```

We want to find out the required type of `key` is when `namespace` is `"a"`.  But the TypeScript type system lacks the sort of expressiveness necessary to directly ask this question.  Conceptually you could imagine specifying that `Namespace` is `"a"`, but you can't do that without also specifying `Val` (there is no "partial" type argument inference; see [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242)).  You could also try to just *call* `fn("a", ???)`, but there's nothing good to put in for `???`; if you put in something random then `Val` will be inferred as the type of that random thing, and you'd probably get a compiler error.

It would be nice if we could call a [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) version of `fn`, of the type:

```
type CurriedFn = <
    Namespace extends keyof ParamMap, Val extends Params<Namespace>
>(t: Namespace) => (u: Val) => string
```

Then you'd call `curriedFn("a")` and it would necessarily return a new function of type `(u: Params<"a">) => string`, which you could then probe with the [`Parameters<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype).

---

One hiccup is that you can't curry arbitrary function types purely at the type level.  That would require TypeScript to have *higher kinded generic types*, such as those requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213).  Luckily there is support for such type manipulations [of generic function *values*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions).  So instead of acting on `Fn` we need to act on `fn`... or on some other value that TypeScript believes is of type `Fn`.

So we need a function to represent the transformation, like this:

```
const curry = <T, U, R>(
    fn: (t: T, u: U) => R
) => (t: T) => (u: U) => fn(t, u);
```

And then if we call it on `fn`, we get the generic type we wanted:

```
const curriedFn = curry(null! as Fn);
//    ^? const curriedFn: <
//         Namespace extends keyof ParamMap, Val extends Params<Namespace>
//    >(t: Namespace) => (u: Val) => string
```

Hooray!

---

An aside about how to proceed if we don't have direct access to `fn`.  We don't really care about `fn` at runtime, just as long as TypeScript *believes* we have a value of type `Fn`.  We can pretend to do that with a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).

Like, here a random function is asserted:

```
const curriedFn = curry((() => { }) as Function as Fn);
```

which works but is a bit verbose. We don't need an actual function:

```
const curriedFn = curry(0 as any as Fn);
```

This is still verbose because of the intermediate assertion.  The tersest way to pretend we have a value of an arbitrary type is probably:

```
const curriedFn = curry(null! as Fn);
```

That works since `null!` uses [the non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-), it's saying "a non-`null` `null`", which can't exist, so it's of type `never`, which can be asserted to any type. "`null!`" is 5 characters long, and I don't think I've seen anything shorter.

All of those result in the same type.

---

And now we can call this with `"a"` as an argument, and it will compile:

```
const takeKey = curriedFn("a");
//    ^? const takeKey: (u: "a1" | "a2") => string
```

And the first parameter of that function is the type we want:

```
type Key = Parameters<typeof takeKey>[0];
//   ^? type Key = "a1" | "a2"
```

Hooray again.

---

So, there you go.  We've at least somewhat programmatically extracted `"a1" | "a2"` from `Fn`.  You can also write `curriedFn("b")` to find `"b1"| "b2"`.

But it's got observable side effects.  It emits the following JavaScript code:

```
const curry = (fn) => (t) => (u) => fn(t, u);
const curriedFn = curry(null);
const takeKey = curriedFn("a");
```

which is useless and just *weird*.  Maybe that's not a huge problem for some use cases, but it's not ideal.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBACgQwE4ILYFkERgXhgb2BmJgQC4YAiBARkpgB8qEAmSgbiJICMLLu6jKtzacAvp1CRYiFKgDOAHgAqMKAA8QUAHYATeTADWUMAHsAZvGRpMEAHy4rc2wG1lAXUlToMAGLbHRS5iADk0KHkIBABjWA0tPQNjM0tZGywAGhgANQQAGzVNHX0nNCUw1Aio2LtgOwAKbXDImKgKCqrWrOSKXLyASlwHeRAkAEttAHNgGYB6WbUANygkMBAACwnJ0m5TZZgNsYNohG1tUxAYblh8rSQoXWB559mZ6NNtEZhogFckVcCyiyAFUsgAlBrBGDmbQUeogChAmA-CjAwY4Bxg4DohzwxE4mD1FEwNFDaHaeFZH79Ly-f5geqMgn4GBiQYIAy+H7aaIgMYfUic7T9YB01b1AAMgtI2jA0v8NJmoo+XzFYwe-kcYoZ2h+eTyAEJ5cLOPMSDAAHoAfm+Ksuao1sJgQTN5vNHRasUKCRKyQspQwmRy+W9xQMaQUig91SgtVdxAaCJg0daBKJvXyBJG4ymSpm4B8AGE-uNHYEoSmvfEw0YTP6I7Ysn1Q4kA+VmjHaon2h3U2T08GBmTs1s3naDghjABpExakvq3T+erUSiK+OWm3vT6XECTqAzsBw4nUQRMahsLOjUcF2AHxwRqB3JQ3-276cmOwuCWeJ4LYjWg5pBgO88BPegz1YSgZiAA)